# Powershell script to clean the most recently used programs on the Start Menu in Vista and Windows 7

Tags: powershell, cleanup, windows

Am looking for a powershell script that cleans (removes) all the items from the most-recently used programs from the Vista/Windows 7 Start menu.

NOTE: Cleaning the items does not mean disabling the MRU behavior - I still want it keep the MRU behavior on; just clean the immediate list of any entries.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows versions post Vista you just need to clean the folder

> %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

As for a script to do that, you could use a regular old command shell (.cmd)

```
del /F %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.lnk
```

Or in PowerShell (thanks to [@alastairs' comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/14071/powershell-script-to-clean-the-most-recently-used-programs-on-the-start-menu-in/14093#comment9993_14093))

```
Remove-Item -Force "${env:USERPROFILE}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent‌​*.lnk"
```

Comment: The PowerShell equivalent (literal translation, and correcting typo in path) is:

Remove-Item -Force "${env:USERPROFILE}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.lnk"

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to the existing answer, but there is an environment variable for the AppData path that you should probably use instead, so:

del /F %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent*.lnk